# Petición con $http.jsonp de AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, nodejs, jsonp

Hago una petición con $http para obtener un JSON del lado del servidor en nodeJS. En el servidor con los logs veo que se envía

```
   console.log(json);
   res.type('json');
   res.json(json);
```

Y el log es el siguiente:

```
[{"codigo":"0","nombre":"nombre","latitud":"lat","longitud":"lon","estado":"ok"},{"codigo":"1","nombre":"nombre","latitud":"lat","longitud":"long","estado":"ko"}]
```

En AngularJS tengo el siguiente código:

```
$http.jsonp("/data").
  success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("PEDIDOS");
  }).
  error(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log("fallé");
  });
```

Y veo que que en el log de AngularJS que falla. 
Puede ser por la estructura del JSON? O se me escapa algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las peticiones usando `$http.jsonp` se utilizan para evitar problemas cuando se hacen peticiones **CORS**, es decir, a un servidor distinto al que está alojada tu aplicación.

Estas peticiones tienen un comportamiento especial y en [este artículo](http://blog.koalite.com/2012/03/sopa-de-siglas-ajax-json-jsonp-y-cors/) tienes una buena explicación del formato **JSONP**.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es cambiar la url de llamada para pasar el parámetro `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

```
$http.jsonp("/data?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").
    success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("PEDIDOS");
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("fallé");
    });
```

Al hacer esto, Angular realizará una petición al servidor con la siguiente url

```
http://servername/data?callback=angular.callbacks._0
```

Y la respuesta del servidor a dicha petición debe ser la siguiente:

```
angular.callbacks._0([{"codigo":"0","nombre":"nombre","latitud":"lat","longitud":"lon","estado":"ok"},{"codigo":"1","nombre":"nombre","latitud":"lat","longitud":"long","estado":"ko"}]);
```

Es decir, el servidor debe envolver el JSON entre `angular.callbacks._0(..JSON..);` que es lo que ha recibido por el parámetro `callback` de la QueryString

Una forma de implementar esto en NodeJs sería:

```
res.jsonp(req.query.callback + '('+ JSON.stringify(obj) + ');');
```

En [este Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mBlfoGiwFXLOPmwxkQEX) se puede ver funcionando (sin la parte de nodejs)

**Nota:** Realmente no sé si necesitas realizar un llamada **CORS**, si no es así te recomendaría que usaras `$http.get` o `$http.post` para trabajar con el formato **JSON** directamente. También podrías implementar el soporte **CORS** en el servidor (este artículo "[JSONP, CORS y como los soportamos desde NodeJS](https://fernetjs.com/2012/09/jsonp-cors-y-como-los-soportamos-desde-nodejs/)" tiene muy buena pinta)

Comment: Gracias por responder. Puedes explicarme un poco más que quieres decir con lo que cito, no me ha quedado muy claro que debería de hacer en NodeJS. Muchas gracias.
 "Después hay que modificar la implementación de servidor para que obtenga el valor del parámetro callback y envuelva los datos en una llamada a un función con ese nombre.

valor_parametro_callback({"p1":"v1", "p2":"v2"});
En el caso de la llamada que hace Angular, la petición a servidor se realiza con callback=angular.callbacks._0 por lo tanto debe devolver lo siguiente"

Comment: Hola @Jfhs19, he reescrito lo de la parte de servidor para explicarlo mejor. Espero que así se entienda mejor. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @rsciriano. Con la explicación que me has dado lo he entendido. Lo he probado y me funciona si mando el JSON harcodeado, sin utilizar la variable que me he creado, pero ese será otro fallo.